Block div / element on webpage (chrome extension development)
I'm learning to create a chrome extension that blocks elements in social media website like feeds, comments etc.
For example, I want to block the Reddit Feed, there is a checkbox to toggle to hide or display the feed. This checkbox sends a message to the content script. Here I'm using var toggle_reddit_feed = document.querySelector("shreddit-feed") to get the feed. then hiding using toggle_reddit_feed.style.display = 'none' . This works when I first load the page, however if I go to a different page within reddit, say the popular feed, the feed doesn't get hidden. It is only after I refresh the feed gets hidden.
So initially in my content script I was doing the following to load the script on DOM:
if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadScript());
  console.log("DOM reloading");
} else {
  console.log("DOM loaded");

  loadScript();
}

But then doing some digging I read that to use MutationObserver()
const redditMain = document.body;
const config = {  attributes: true, childList: true };

var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for (var mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === "childList") {
        console.log("DOM updated");
        loadScript();
      }
  }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(redditMain, config);

Both ways I'm not able to achieve hiding the page
I also was checking the Chrome Extension documentation. I saw from one of the beginner samples like the this one, it also has the same problem
I know these extensions / tool already exists but I want to learn about JavaScript and Chrome extension development.


Replace attributes: true with subtree: true. 2) Remove for loop and check for an element you need via document.querySelector. 3) Change your "matches" in manifest.json to the entire site e.g. "*://*.foo.com/*".

